# Recursively replace type by other type in a templated type

Tags: c++, templates

I'm looking for a way to recursively replace a type in a template. More specifically, turn `T[N]` into `std::array<T, N>`. The problem is doing this recursively if non-type template parameters are included.

Currently, I have the following code:

```
template<typename T>
struct replaced {
    using type = T;
};

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct replaced<T[N]> {
    using type = std::array<typename replaced<T>::type, N>;
};

template<template<typename...> typename T, typename... Ts>
struct replaced<T<Ts...>> {
    using type = T<typename replaced<Ts>::type...>;
};
```

Test cases without non-type template parameters work fine, but as soon as a non-type template parameter is introduced, it no longer works:

```
// this works (simple replacement)
static_assert(std::is_same_v<replaced<int[3]>::type, std::array<int, 3>>);

// this also works (nested types)
static_assert(std::is_same_v<
    replaced<std::tuple<int[2], std::pair<int, float[3]>>>::type,
    std::tuple<std::array<int, 2>, std::pair<int, std::array<float, 3>>>>);

// this doesn't work (non-type template parameters)
static_assert(std::is_same_v<
    replaced<std::array<int[2], 2>>::type,
    std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 2>>);

// instead this works, but shouldn't
static_assert(std::is_same_v<
    replaced<std::array<int[2], 2>>::type,
    std::array<int[2], 2>>);
```

[Link to compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/bKTqGx)

I understand that the variadic template template parameter doesn't work for non-type templates parameters. Is there any way of modifying the definitions of `replaced` to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, cool idea!

But as much as it sucks, as of C++20 there's no way to handle a generic, variadic mix of type and non-type elements. You just have to start carving out corner cases like with `std::array`.

This seems to fix *that* specific problem, but of course it only helps for classes that follow the same pattern as `std::array`

```cpp
template <template<typename, auto> class TC, typename T, auto N>
struct replaced<TC<T, N>> {
    using type = TC<typename replaced<T>::type, N>;
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/3j13W3

Comment: Nice fix. I'd add `template<class... Ts>
using replaced_t = typename replaced<Ts...>::type;` to make the usage more friendly too.